# Powershell-Update attribute "departmentNumber"

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following script - it works except for the departmentNumber.  Any ideas?

```
# Import AD Module             
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

# Import CSV into variable $users    
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\users.csv

# Loop through CSV file and update users if they exist        
foreach ($user in $users) {
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'" - Properties * | 
Set-ADUser  -EmailAddress $($user.EmailAddress) -Title $($user.Title)  -Office $($user.Office)  -OfficePhone $($user.OfficePhone) -departmentNumber $($user.departmentNumber) }
```

**EDIT:**

I tried the following using the "-Add" operator:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\users.csv
foreach ($user in $users) {
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'" -Properties * | 
Set-ADUser  -Add @{departmentNumber = "$($user.departmentNumber)"}
}
```

And the following, using the "-Replace" operator:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\users.csv
foreach ($user in $users) {
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'" -Properties * | 
Set-ADUser  -Replace @{departmentNumber = "$($user.departmentNumber)"}
}
```

Still no luck - do I have the syntax messed up?

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see the CSV contents. If you're not getting an error message, then presumably the value of `$user.departNumber` is `$null` or similarly not what you expect.

Comment: I'm using a test CSV with one record using the same columns listed in the Set clause above, and each field has a value to input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm taking a quick look at the help for Set-ADUser: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx

I see a parameter for -Department, but not one for -DepartmentNumber

Will it work within your company's structure to just use -Department ?

For a custom attribute, you should be able to use the -Add parameter

```psh
-Add @{otherTelephone='555-222-1111', '555-222-3333'; otherMobile='555-222-9999' }
```

In order to use -Add or -Replace, you'll need to use a hashtable as your input instead of a string.
Here's a quick set of commands I used to convert a string into a single item hashtable:

```psh
$DeptNo = 'test'
$hash = @{}
$hash.Add('DepartmentNumber',$DeptNo)
$hash
```

Output from $hash:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
DepartmentNumber               test
```

I think you'll then be able to use -Add $hash to get it to do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I am but a small cog in the big wheel, and that's the field "they" want populated.  The departmentNumber parameter is under the Attribute Editor tab only when viewing Advanced Features, so I'm wondering if it's some sort of hidden parameter or something else...

Comment: For this,  you want to use the -Replace or -Add parameter. They're specifically designed for changing attributes that aren't changable with the normal parameters.

Comment: I found an article that goes into a little more detal on this. You might run into some difficulty because these parameters want a hashtable as input, you might have to do some trial and error to get it working. I can't help because I don't have a test environment handy. [link](http://windowsitpro.com/active-directory/meet-set-aduser-all-purpose-hammer)

Comment: Hm, still no luck - I'm using a CSV ; must I use a different delimiter, perhaps?

Comment: Your other parameters are expecting strings as input, so they're working. This one is expecting a hashtable. Someone will probably beat me to it, but I'll see if I can figure out how to convert a string to a hashtable.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know what to look for.

Comment: I made one more edit to the solution with some ideas on how to convert to a hashtable. Hopefully that's the last piece of information you need to finish up!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code that got it working:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $samName -Add @{'departmentNumber'="$UserDept"}
```

It is important to note you can only use `-Add` if nothing is there
otherwise use `-Replace`

`$UserDept` was a number but the quotes make it a string
and the attribute must have single quotes around it.